# How does a ThreadPoolExecutor that is created using the constructor with BlockingQueue<Runnable> as an argument, enqueue Callables?

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor, callable, blockingqueue

The constructor for `ThreadPoolExecutor` has the type argument for the `BlockingQueue` as `Runnable`.
Let's suppose I have a `ThreadPoolExecutor` declared like this

```
ThreadPoolExecutor customThreadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(numberOfAvailableProcessors,
                                numberOfAvailableProcessors, 2L,
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(),
                                Executors.defaultThreadFactory(),
                                new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor) {
                                        // Do something here to handle it
                                    }
                                });
```

My question is that when is do something like:

```
customThreadPool.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer call() throws Exception {
                    return Math.toIntExact(Thread.currentThread().getId());
                }
            })
```

**How does the `ThreadPool` handle this even though I have specified the type argument of the `Queue` to be `Runnable`?**
**How will this task be queued?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it wraps your `Callable` task as a `RunnableFuture` before queueing or executing.

This `RunnableFuture` implements `Runnable` interface (in addition to the `Future`).

So all callables could be queued and executed without any issue.

Have a look at `AbstractExecutorService` source for further info.